# mongod.exe has stopped working error

Tags: mongodb, installation

I installed mongoDB 3.2.4. I am on a Windows 7 64-bit system.

After installing mongoDB, I specified dbpath as "c:\data" and also set the environment variable. Now, whenever I try to execute `mongod/mongo`, I get a popup that says "mongod.exe has stopped working" or "mongo.exe has stopped working", like shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

This is what I found in the "view problem details" of the error dialogue box:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH   Application
>   Name: mongod.exe   Application Version:   0.0.0.0   Application
>   Timestamp:    56de0c29   Fault Module Name:   mongod.exe   Fault Module
>   Version:  0.0.0.0   Fault Module Timestamp:   56de0c29   Exception
>   Code: c000001d   Exception Offset:    0000000000c04713   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1   Locale ID:   1033   Additional
>   Information 1:    7c1e   Additional Information
>   2:    7c1ee2ba56224cd9352de03840feb4d9   Additional Information 3:    c5d2
>   Additional Information 4: c5d247ac4cbf220bef4183808293e174
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>     C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the issue. Then I uninstalled it and installed a stable version 2.6.12. It work well, you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a compatibility issue between windows7 and MongoDB (version **3.x.x**).

Two solutions:

1. Apply the patch provided by Microsoft. 
   **https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2731284**
2. Downgrade the MongoDB version. Go for version **2.x.x**

Comment: But i don't want to downgrade MongoDB version. need to keep 3.X.X version. Is there any other option..?